# Converting coordinate ETRS89/LCC to WGS84 Lat Long

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude

I need to convert a massive amount of coordinates in the ETRS89 format to WGS84 Lat Long.

As far as I know ETRS89 and WGS84 are nearly the same, but they have totally different values.

I need the WGS84 coordinates for bing maps.

Would be great if theres a simple solution in c# for this problem.

Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

First choice for such transformation is the [Proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) project. There are several ports available, e.g. to Java ([Java Proj.4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jproj4/)), JavaScript ([Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/)), .NET ([Proj4Net](http://proj4net.codeplex.com/)), etc.

Command-line tool `cs2cs.exe` is used to transform coordinates, the command would be like this:

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:3034 +to +init=epsg:4326 {name of your text-file containing massive amount of coordinates}
```

which is equivalent to

```
cs2cs +proj=lcc +lat_1=35 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4000000 +y_0=2800000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
    +to +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs {name of your text-file containing massive amount of coordinates}
```

In case you prefer C# my personal favorites are [DotSpatial.Projections](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/releases/view/621128) and [ProjApi](http://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/Public/BDB/Tools/proj4/) (file `csharp-4.7.0.zip`)

Example for DotSpatial:

```
double[] xy = new double[2];
xy[0] = 12345;
xy[1] = 67890;
double[] z = new double[1];
z[0] = 1;
ProjectionInfo pStart = KnownCoordinateSystems.Projected.Europe.ETRS1989LCC;
ProjectionInfo pEnd = KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984;
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xy, z, pStart, pEnd, 0, 1);
```

Example with Proj-API:

```
var src = new Projection(@"+proj=lcc +lat_1=35 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4000000 +y_0=2800000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"),
var dst = new Projection(@"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

double[] x = { -116, -117, -118, -119, -120, -121 };
double[] y = { 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 };
double[] z = { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

Projection.Transform(src, dst, x, y);
```